# Why didn't the hero association use Hitoshi the guy with the brainwashing quirk to make AFO leak information?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Why they didn't use him which such a strong quirk? Did it got explained in the anime or manga, or did the author just forgot he even existed?

Answer (score 2):

Since there isn't any objective answer to this, we can only speculate on the matter. Probably the obvious and simple reason is that **Shinso** isn't a fully fledged hero and **exposing a kid to AFO interrogation** isn't quite the most ethical thing to do and also AFO probably has barriers and others **countermeasures to prevent brainwashing** or mind reading.

Answer (score 2):

During the Joint Training Arc Shinso explained some of the limitations of his quirk, namely that he couldn't make brainwashed people do anything that requires using their brain in a non-trivial capacity or that would require them to speak.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think he could make the brainwashed talk. If he did, he would have just made Deku forfeit instead of having him walk out of the arena. Also, don't you think that if the guy who absolutely trashed All Might was in front of him, he would be a little scared.